# Graphql directives doesn't work for mutation input arguments when pass the arguments as external variables

Tags: graphql, arguments, apollo-server, mutation

I am implementing custom Graphql directives to validate client input. A sample code as below, I referred to the official examples here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/#enforcing-value-restrictions

```
const { ApolloServer, gql, SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = require('apollo-server');
const { GraphQLScalarType, GraphQLNonNull } = require('graphql');

const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @validateInput on FIELD_DEFINITION | INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION | ARGUMENT_DEFINITION

type Mutation {
 sampleMutation(
    test1: String @validateInput
    nestedInput: SampleMutationInput
  ): String
}

input SampleMutationInput {
  test2: String @validateInput
}
`;
```

The implementation of the directive logic:

```
class ValidateInputDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitInputFieldDefinition(field) {
    this.wrapType(field);
  }

  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    this.wrapType(field);
  }

  visitArgumentDefinition(argument) {
    console.log('visitArgumentDefinition', argument);
    this.wrapType(argument);
  }

  wrapType(field) {
    console.log('wrapType', field);
    if (
      field.type instanceof GraphQLNonNull &&
      field.type.ofType instanceof GraphQLScalarType
    ) {
      field.type = new GraphQLNonNull(
        new ValidateInputType(field.type.ofType)
      );
    } else if (field.type instanceof GraphQLScalarType) {
      field.type = new ValidateInputType(field.type);
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Not a scalar type: ${field.type}`);
    }
  }
}

class ValidateInputType extends GraphQLScalarType {
  constructor(type) {
    super({
      name: 'ValidatedInput',
      serialize(value) {
        return value;
      },
      parseValue(value) {
        const result = type.parseValue(value);
        
        if (/[?!]/.test(result)) {
          throw new Error('Invalid characters');
        }
        return result;
      },
      parseLiteral(ast) {
        const result = type.parseLiteral(ast);
        
        if (/[?!]/.test(result)) {
          throw new Error('Invalid characters');
        }
        return result;
      },
    });
  }
}

export default { validateInput: ValidateInputDirective };
```

It works as expected for the input field 'test2', but for the argument 'test1', it works when the String value is directly passed to the mutation, then the method "parseLiteral" is called and the validation logic applied to the input value. However, when I pass the 'test1' value as external variables (via JSON format), the directive doesn't work and the method "parserValue" never be called.

What I found so far:

1. "parserValue" is used when the input comes from variable JSON. "parseLiteral" is used when the input comes directly from the query/mutation.
2. It seems a bug in Graphql tools according to https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/issues/789

I want to understand:

1. what's the real difference between an argument passed by variable and directly pass to mutation?
2. is there an alternate way to apply the directives to an argument to avoid this issue?
3. If this is really a bug with Graphql, does it fixed now? Which version should I use to resolve the issue?